# Kendo UI Mobile - Camera feature with HTML5 input tag responsiveness very slow

Tags: html, kendo-ui

Implemented camera feature using HTML5 input tag.
Requires atleast 5 to 6 clicks before opening camera. Tried on iOS 6 Safari browser and Goggle chrome browser on Android.
Refered below js files :
1. jquery-1.8.3.js 
2. kendo.mobile.min.js
Do we need to include any js file

Code :

```
    <div data-role="view" id="tabstrip-camera" data-title="camera" data-layout="mobile-tabstrip" id="Camera">
         <!--Camera Code-->
         <input data-click="alert('clciked');" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture>
    </div>
```

Even when tried with simple HTML5 button tag the response is slow and same observation is used.

Please can any one help ? Do we need to include any js file.

Answer (score 0):

Is your intent to deploy an actual mobile app to a phone or tablet device, or just to use Kendo Mobile widgets in a desktop web browser?

If you are going to deploy to a device, then you should be building on top of PhoneGap / Cordova, and could use PhoneGap's image capture function:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using kendo ui mobile widget  for developing mobile web app for IPhone safari browser and Android default browser

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the Kendo UI Q3 service pack that was released this week and see if this fixes it.

The original Kendo UI Q3 release had some issues with the touch/mouse events due to the major change we did in event handling in order to support systems with both mouse and touch (Chrome/FF on Windows 8).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using the kendo ui mobile Q3 release (released on 14th dec 2012). Is the last week release patch to Q3 release or a new release ? It would be really helpful If you can share the link to download this release ?